# CakePHP XML view file

Tags: xml, rest, cakephp, layout, view

I would like to set CakePHP framework to allow page rendering when view file does not exist. I have all the definition set on layout and do not need extra empty files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use controller property `autoRender`.

```
function beforeRender() {
  $this->autoRender = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: You can also put that into individual Controller methods to do it on an action-by-action basis.

Answer (score -2):

Ah yes... `$this->render(false);`

Comment: obviously you are trying to gain points but it is not the correct way